# How to fix bash encoding issue?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

I am getting this type of output on every command on git bash (Windows 8.1)

on every command my output has some unresolved or encoding issue. How to fix this?

```
←[37;41m
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  [PDOException]
       ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
machi  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  ne actively refused it.
       ←[39;49m
←[37;41m
       ←[39;49m
```

Actual Screenshot of bash

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is not unresolved encoding, those are shell color codes (see mklement0's comment below for precise description).
You need to run it under a shell (bash on cygwin for example) in order for it to interpret the colors.

Disable colors by running:

```
git config --global color.ui false
```

Comment: Can we fix this in git bash ?

Comment: Nicely done; quibble: these codes aren't Bash-specific, they are [_ANSI_ escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Good point, used shell on my second phrase because of that but mistakenly had it in the first one still.